# SVN: shows edits on a file with authorships

Tags: svn, diff, ownership, author

I've a question:
We are using SVN as way to manage our sources. Now, i would like to take a file and see who committed each part of the text.
Basically would be a big diff that takes all the version and as output shows the texts highlighting who committed which part.

For example:
A committed "Hi, today is Monday"
B committed the change "Hi, today is Thursday"
C committed the change "Hello, today is Thursday"

the output will be smt like "Hello[C],today is[A] Thursday[B]" (obviously not with brackets but coloring the edits with different colors per authors.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of `svn blame FILE` ? It does exactly that. It looks better in a GUI client though.

EDIT: that's usually possible on a per line basis, unlike your example.

Comment: @LazyBadger true. With tortoise you can easily "blame former revisions" to get the former author.

Comment: I can blame in CLI also, but but can't suggest blamebased-only **good** workflow from OP's requested output